# Hazelcast Hibernate second-level cache configuration

Tags: hibernate, configuration, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I'm experimenting with using Hazelcast as the second-level cache for Hibernate.  I'm unsure where to specify the cache configuration.  I've added the following to my Hazelcast XML:

```
<map name="com.blah.entity.*">
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>3600</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>600</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <near-cache>
        <max-size>5</max-size>
        <time-to-live-seconds>3600</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>600</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
        <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
    </near-cache>
</map>
```

However, when I use JVisualVM (with JMX plugin) to view the Map MBean, I see that the size of the map is 21 (which is larger than my max size of 5).

The maps 'config' attribute on the MBean shows that my configuration has been applied:

```
MapConfig{name='com.blah.entity.*',
  inMemoryFormat=BINARY',
  backupCount=1,
  asyncBackupCount=0,
  timeToLiveSeconds=3600,
  maxIdleSeconds=600,
  evictionPolicy='LRU',
  evictionPercentage=25,
  maxSizeConfig=MaxSizeConfig{maxSizePolicy='PER_NODE',
    size=5},
  readBackupData=false,
  nearCacheConfig=NearCacheConfig{timeToLiveSeconds=3600,
    maxSize=5,
    evictionPolicy='LRU',
    maxIdleSeconds=600,
    invalidateOnChange=true,
    inMemoryFormat=BINARY,
    cacheLocalEntries=false},
  mapStoreConfig=null,
  mergePolicyConfig='com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy',
  wanReplicationRef=null,
  listenerConfigs=[],
  mapIndexConfigs=[]}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the config, or am I misreading the JMX data?

**EDIT**

Just to clear up any confusion, [the documentation](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html/hibernate2levelcache.html) says the following:

> Hazelcast creates a separate distributed map for each Hibernate cache
>   region. So, these regions can be configured easily via Hazelcast map
>   configuration. You can define backup, eviction, TTL and Near Cache
>   properties.

I want to set the max-size property on the maps for the cache regions for my entities because I don't want the cache to expand without limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my configuration is correct, but there is a bug in Hazelcast 3.2.1 - 3.2.4 for [Wildcard Configuration](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html/wildcardconfiguration.html)

The problem is the wildcard in the map name: `<map name="com.blah.entity.*">`  If I use a fully qualified name for the map, e.g. `com.blah.entity.User`, the map configuration is picked up correctly.  I verified using JMX that the map configuration is applied to the cache correctly.

I've been assured that this issue will be fixed in Hazelcast 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You specify the path to the configuration using the following property inside your Hibernate configuration `hibernate.cache.hazelcast.configuration_file_path`.

Comment: I've already done that.  My question is about how to configure the parameters of the cache in Hibernate (e.g. max size).

Comment: You configure those values inside the hazelcast.xml file not inside the Hibernate configuration or maybe I misunderstood the question again.

Comment: I know how to specify the hazelcast configuration in Hibernate.  I can use JMX to see that my configuration has been loaded (see the original post).  What I want to know is how to edit the hazelcast configuration XML to tune the Hibernate cache parameters.

Comment: What parameters? You don't set Hibernate configurations inside the Hazelcast configuration. Sorry but I don't get what exactly you are trying to do. Do you have any example of configuration properties you want to set?

Comment: My original post provides an example of what I'm trying to set.  As per [the documentation](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html/hibernate2levelcache.html) "Hazelcast creates a separate distributed map for each Hibernate cache region. So, these regions can be configured easily via Hazelcast map configuration. You can define backup, eviction, TTL and Near Cache properties."  It's these map properties for each Hibernate cache region that I'm trying to set.